# Does Flutter has the possibility to use only a if condition inside the build method?

Tags: flutter, if-statement

I worked with flutter for almost a year and since it wasn't production-ready for web development I needed to switch to react.

To render object conditionally inside my build method I had to put an if-else statement rendering my custom widget if the condition was met or a random empty container in the other case.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Container(
   child: condition == true 
       ? new MyCustomWidget() 
       : new Container() //Random empty container to fill the else statement
 )
)
```

Even if this doesn't cause any rendering problem, it's still can be ambiguous for someone reading the code. After working with react I saw that it provides a way to display only the if block using the following notation:

```
<div>
  {condition == true && <MyCustomReactComponent/>} //this block is displayed only if the condition is met
</div>
```

I was guessing if flutter has a way to do something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I use `Column` in situations like these, you can declare multiple conditions depending upon which widget you want to display for which condition.**

```
Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       if(your condition) CustomWidgetOne(),
       if(your condition) CustomWidgetTwo(),
       if(your condition) CustomWidgetThree(),
           
      ],
  ),
```

Comment: This is so far the best shortcut to what I meant. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which condition you want to display a specific widget.

For exemple, if you want to display a side bar widget only on wide webpages you can use the `LayoutBuilder` widget which you can use like @media on vanilla web.

Otherwise you'll need to use ternary operator as you did.

If you want a more complete answer you can check a [talk that Mariano Zorrilla on the subject on the 28/01/21](http://%20https://youtu.be/hpuCjDHkmFU?t=5759)

Comment: Ok, thanks. No, that's not the case I need. I left flutter for its routing system. I was aware of the various builders. However, my question's purpose was to understand if fluter had (or has introduced more recently) an alternative way to the ternary operator. On small conditions, this is not a big issue, but when the size of the page starts to increase this logic can become counterintuitive and make the code messy.

Comment: For now, with what i know, there is no alternative.

When it comes to big pages/screens, you just need to use an architecture and divide your screen in multiples littles widgets.

Comment: When the expression you're handing to a ternary operator is getting large, it's time to refactor!  The ternary should never be much longer than `someCondition ? Widget1() : Widget2() `

Comment: I agree with you Randal, but sometimes creating another custom widget just to wrap another widget inside padding or something similar can also become an anti-pattern. It will be like building a custom function sum(a,b) just to do a+b. I know there must be a balance between the two options, but I don't think that an inline condition is always the best choice

Answer (score 0):

You can always return null, as if you're passing no child at all.

Comment: Adding null it's never a safe decision. Even if null should never be executed, it might cause issues later on when the code gets modified

Comment: Better to return a empty Container() or an empty SizedBox().

Comment: I disagree. Using null in this context imo isn't bad. I also personally am not a fan of returning empty Containers as you are still returning something while you actually don't want to return anything.